# Limit DevExpress RichEditControl to a single page

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress, paging

RichEditControl in DXperience WinForms has a view named 'PrintLayoutView'. This view displays documents as pageable, rather than infinite. I'd like to limit the control to show only first page of the document and control page navigation programmatically.

Is this accomplishable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XtraRichEdit does not provide an elegant way to implement this task.  The only solution is to turn off all scrollbars (RichEditControl.Options.HorizontalScrollbar.Visibility and RichEditControl.Options.VerticalScrollbar.Visibility) and finally create commands to programmatically change the current Page, you should execute the RichEdit's NextPageCommand.  To learn about commands, please refer to the [Commands](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument9328) topic.

**Update**

```
    GoToPageCommand goToPageCommand = new GoToPageCommand(richEditControl1);
    ICommandUIState state = goToPageCommand.CreateDefaultCommandUIState();
    state.EditValue = 10;
    goToPageCommand.ForceExecute(state);
```

Comment: Thanks, any way to delete the remaining pages from the document? Like `RichEditControl.Document.Pages[1].Remove();`

Comment: Hmm, the problem is that the XtraRichEdit does not work with Pages and it is rather difficult to delete Pages ...  At least, there is no a public API for this task.  So, I would like to ask you to describe your original task, i.e. what you need to implement using the XtraRichEdit.  We will try to find an acceptable solution for you.

Comment: In our software, we have two modes, demo and registered. In demo mode, the software shows only a preview of full document, one page. So the conversion model is "Register to see all pages". Any suggestions? Maybe we can track when the page number changes and return viewing to the first page?

Comment: Unfortunately, this algorithm won't work.  I understand what you want to achieve and why, but, we cannot provide a solution based on pages.  We can suggest that you show a limited number of paragraphs in the RichEdit.  This algorithm can be implemented with ease.

Comment: As the paragraphs can vary in length, this is going to be less consistent. Is it possible to limit contents based on length? E.g. show maximum 500 characters? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Please let me know if this is correct approach:       if (richEditControl1.Document.Range.Length > 500)
            {
                richEditControl1.Document.Delete(richEditControl1.Document.CreateRange(500, richEditControl1.Document.Range.Length - 500));


            }

Comment: Your code will work in case of simple documents (i.e. if the 500 symbol is not within a table or a field).  If you want to handle these situations as well, post a comment here and I will post another code here ...

Comment: Would appreciate a proper sample.

Comment: Also, GoToPageCommand doesn't appear to be working in the latest XtraRichEdit release.